# I'm using cocoapods to implement a dynamic button but doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode

```
import UIKit
import DynamicButton

class Viola: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var dynamicButton: UIButton!

    let dynamicButton = DynamicButton(style: DynamicButtonStyle.hamburger)

    //var confettiView: SAConfettiView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dynamicButton                 = DynamicButton()
        dynamicButton.lineWidth           = 3
        dynamicButton.strokeColor         = .white
        dynamicButton.highlightStokeColor = .gray
        dynamicButton.style = DynamicButtonStyle.hamburger

        dynamicButton.setStyle(DynamicButtonStyle.close, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        //dynamicButton.style = DynamicButtonStyle.hamburger

    }
}
```

The link for the installation is :
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/DynamicButton/3.1.0/

Comment: Corrected indent. Questioner should show error message.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that library but it is clear that you are creating `DynamicButton` three times. I think you should determine which button you use at first.

For example, what happen for doing only this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dynamicButton                 = DynamicButton(style: DynamicButtonStyle.hamburger)
    dynamicButton.lineWidth           = 3
    dynamicButton.strokeColor         = .white
    dynamicButton.highlightStokeColor = .gray
    self.view.addSubview(dynamicButton)
}
```

Comment: it shows error in last line ie. self.view.addSubView(dynamicButton) which says  "value of type 'UI View' has no member 'addSubView'" and do I have to manually make a button on VC and link it to the code ?

Comment: @SARANSHVYAS Sorry "v" should be lowercase. I edited my answer, and also check this link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview

Comment: the icon is being displayed but no animation can be seen !!

Comment: @SARANSHVYAS that's why I didn't write any animation code. you may need to use `setStyle:animated:` method to make animation (as long as I read the library's documet)

Comment: I've already added this in my code "dynamicButton.setStyle(DynamicButtonStyle.close, animated: true) " still no change

Comment: just after "self.view.addSubview(dynamicButton)"

Comment: @SARANSHVYAS Though I don't know the reason it won't change the style, it doesn't make sense because you set hamburger style just before that. I don't know what do you want to, but I think this method is used to change style after some trigger e.g. tap button.

Comment: yes I want this animation to be triggered with the button is tapped, any idea how that can be done ?

Comment: @SARANSHVYAS I know how to archive that but, it isn't already related to the original question, you should investigate by googling or else. the official sample app may also helps you: https://github.com/yannickl/DynamicButton/tree/master/Example/DynamicButtonExample